# Create an Alias Directory inside a Virtual Host

Tags: windows, apache2, alias, virtualhost, wampserver

*I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552081/using-a-directory-in-virtualhost-servername), [here](http://www.rafael-chacon.com/post/9903470026/rails-wordpress-apache-integration), [here](http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2006/10/10/Apache-Directory-Aliases-and-Virtual-Directories), [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html), and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) before asking this question. I guess my search skills are weak.*

I am using the [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) version `2.2e`. I have a need like, I need a virtual path inside a virtual host. Let me say the two hosts that I have.

#### Primary Virtual Host (Localhost)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

#### My Apps Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.ptrl
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps"
    ErrorLog "logs/apps-ptrl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/apps-ptrl-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

#### My Blog Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.praveen-kumar.ptrl
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog"
    ErrorLog "logs/praveen-kumar-ptrl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/praveen-kumar-ptrl-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

My requirement now is to have `http://apps.ptrl/blog/` and `http://blog.praveen-kumar.ptrl/` should be the same directory. One thing I thought of is, moving the `blog` folder inside the `apps` folder, but it is connected with `Git` and other stuffs are there, so it is not possible to move the folder.

So, I thought of creating an `alias` to the `VirtualHost` in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.ptrl
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps"
    ErrorLog "logs/apps-ptrl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/apps-ptrl-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

    # The alias to the blog!
    Alias /blog "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog"
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I tried to access `http://apps.ptrl/blog`, I am getting an `Error 403 Forbidden` page.

[image: Forbidden]

Am I doing the right thing? If you need to look at the access log, and error log, they are here:

```
# Access Log
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2012:09:53:11 +0530] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 403 206
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2012:09:53:11 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2012:09:53:53 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6935
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2012:09:53:53 +0530] "GET /app/blog/thumb.png HTTP/1.1" 404 216
# Error Log
[Sun Oct 14 09:53:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog
[Sun Oct 14 09:53:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps/favicon.ico
[Sun Oct 14 09:53:53 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps/app/blog, referer: http://apps.ptrl/
```

Waiting eagerly for some help. I am ready to provide more info, if needed.

---

### Update #1: Changed VirtualHosts declaration according to the instructions given by [felipsmartins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262820/felipsmartins):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.ptrl
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps"
    ErrorLog "logs/apps-ptrl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/apps-ptrl-access.log" common
    # The alias to the blog!
    Alias /blog "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog"
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Update #2: Another Issue:

I am able to access the site. The physical links are working now. i.e., I am able to open `http://apps.ptrl/blog/index.php` but not `http://apps.ptrl/blog/view-1.ptf`, which gets translated to `http://apps.ptrl/blog/index.php?page=view&id=1`. Any solutions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Note, if you are creating an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) to a directory outside of your [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot), you may need to explicitly permit access to target directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.ptrl
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps"
    ErrorLog "logs/apps-ptrl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/apps-ptrl-access.log" common

    # Puts here, before Directory directive :) 
    Alias /blog "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog"

    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/apps">        
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note, too, that URL-path (first Alias part) is case-sensitive even on case-insensitive file systems.

Also, check permissions from `C:/Wamp/vhosts/ptrl/praveen-kumar/blog` directory.

**Reference**

- [Apache Module mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)
- [Apache Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Comment: For more details see the Apache guide , [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: @felipsmartines Please see the updated answer. I restarted the Apache2 server too. No luck.

Comment: Seriously, what was the issue. I did the same before, but didn't work! Whatever, you are a magician!!! :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar, So it worked? Sorry, my English is terrible O.o

Comment: yeah, it worked. But I have an issue. See, I am able to access the site, but the `.htaccess` is not working. It says `404 Not Found`. Can you help?