# virtualhost keeps redirecting to deleted alias information

Tags: apache, prestashop, alias, virtualhost, prestashop-1.6

I have a DigitalOcean droplet (i.e. a VPS server), with Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.2.

I had 4 virtualhosts configured, with 4 different domains pointing to 4 different folders, no problem.

I needed to point a 5th domain (let's call it `www.someshop.tld`) containing a PrestaShop installation.

I added the following `Alias` to the `apache2/sites-available/domain1.conf` file so that `www.domain1.tld/someshop` would lead to `www/prestashop`, and it worked fine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName www.domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/directory1

    Alias /someshop /www/prestashop    #Alias line
</VirtualHost>
```

I did this as a temporary measure so I could have a working site publicly accessible, (so I could access `www/prestashop` publicly before I had configured `www.someshop.tld` DNS settings, 'A' record, Nameservers, etc.).

I now don't need to do this any more, so I deleted the `Alias` line from the `.conf` file so it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/directory1
</VirtualHost>
```

and added a new `someshop.conf` that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.someshop.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/prestashop
</VirtualHost>
```

I then re-enabled both the `.conf` files in `apache2/sites-enabled`, and restarted apache with `service apache2 restart`.

However, when I go to `www.someshop.tld`, it continues to do a URL redirect to `www.domain1.tld/prestashop` (where there's this message: "Not Found, The requested URL `/someshop` was not found on this server").

I waited for a couple of hours before posting this question because I thought it might just be a "propagation" issue. So far it's still doing this.

My question: is this something that should clear up by waiting for it, or do I need to fix something else? E.g., is there some way for me to flush the old virtualhost `Alias` information?

Comment: have you seem apache log fie ?

Comment: Does this also happen on other machines/browsers that have never been to the domain? Just to rule out a caching issue. Not sure how browsers cache redirects, but I think I've seen instances of it happening.

Comment: What about prestashop url settings in the backoffice, did you change them too?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the site from apache config?

```
$ sudo a2dissite test.com.conf  #Remove symlink
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

This would remove the symlink. You can then create the symlink again with the proper configurations that you like.

Comment: Is there any reason a symlink would persist even if the .conf file was deleted entirely? I'm somehow getting a phantom redirect to a virtual server that I've deleted.